# Voltage drop in Li-po charging circuit based on MCP73871T

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I created a schematic including a Li-po charging IC [MCP73871T](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf) and a boost converter powered by USB 5 V. The switch can alternate the boost voltage output between 9 and 12 V.

Problem:

12 V state:

- The coil outputs an audible noise with a decaying frequency
- The Stat2 LED is flickering and then stays ON

9 V state:

- The coil outputs audible noise, then turns silent
- The Stat2 LED is flickering, then turns OFF

Investigation:

- Measuring the output returns 9.2 V and 11.5 V depending on the switch position
- Bypassing the battery IC outputs 9.2 V and 12.65 V with no audible noise

No battery is currently attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This issue can be layout related. Can you show it?

Comment: Thanks, I just added the layout

Comment: The peak current of the boost converter seams to trigger a kind of overload logic in the MCP73871. What is the boost converter output load?

Comment: It's a 12V fan that draws around 400mA

Comment: So I expect 2.4 A peak current at the 5 V input. This cannot work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm measuring the power draw through a USB meter and it outputs 0,38A @ 4,87V if bypassing the battery IC (all working as it should) and 0,34A @ 4,9V without bypassing. I assumed 0.4A is the peak current.

Comment: 12 V x 0.4 A = 4.8 W. 4.8 W / 5 V = 0.96 A minimum. Depending on the amount of ripple current in the inductor and the duty cycle I came to worst case 2.4 A peak.